# I am trying to fill a listbox with items from List<> c#

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I am trying to fill a listbox with items from a List<> and be able to call it in different forms. But it doesn't seem to loading on to the other form. Thanks for any help.

```
private void frmAdminMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product prod1 = new Product(001, "Milk", "Dairy", 1.20m, 10, 1.027m);
        Product prod2 = new Product(002, "Cheese", "Dairy", 2.80m, 20, 0.300m);
        Product prod3 = new Product(003, "Apple", "Fruit", 0.50m, 10, 0.136m);
        Product prod4 = new Product(004, "Orange", "Fruit", 0.80m, 20, 0.145m);
        Product prod5 = new Product(005, "Tomato", "Veg", 2.50m, 15, 0.110m);
        Product prod6 = new Product(006, "Onion", "Veg", 1.50m, 10, 0.105m);
        Product prod7 = new Product(007, "Lamb", "Meat", 4.50m, 10, 0.340m);
        Product prod8 = new Product(008, "Chicken", "Meat", 3.50m, 10, 0.907m);
        products.Add(prod1);
        products.Add(prod2);
        products.Add(prod3);
        products.Add(prod4);
        products.Add(prod5);
        products.Add(prod6);
        products.Add(prod7);
        products.Add(prod8);


       FillProductListBox();
    }

    private void FillProductListBox()
    {
        lstViewStock.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            lstViewStock.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText("\t"));
        }
    }
```

This trying to call the listbox in another form

```
ListBox tmpProducts;

    public frmEnterShop()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<Product> shoppingCart = new List<Product>();

    public frmEnterShop(ListBox shippedIn)
        : this()
    {
        tmpProducts = shippedIn;
        MessageBox.Show("Total of " + tmpProducts.Items.Count, "Number of Items"); // view-Output
    }

 private void frmEnterShop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[0]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[1]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[2]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[3]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[4]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[5]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[6]);
       lstViewProducts.Items.Add(tmpProducts.Items[7]);
    }
```

Comment: *Side-note*: What you're doing in `frmEnterShop_Load` should be in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example using

```
listbox.DataSource = something;
```

Notice the implementation of the ToString-Method for displaying in the listbox.

Here is my test code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public class Product
    {
        String name;

        public Product(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IList<Product> list = new List<Product>() { new Product("abc"), new Product("def") };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.DataSource = list;
        }

    }
}
```

One more tip: do not use so called magic numbers for the product IDs. Use a incremental variable for this:

```
int id = 0;
Product prod1 = new Product(++id, "Milk", "Dairy", 1.20m, 10, 1.027m);
Product prod2 = new Product(++id, "Cheese", "Dairy", 2.80m, 20, 0.300m);
Product prod3 = new Product(++id, "Apple", "Fruit", 0.50m, 10, 0.136m);
Product prod4 = new Product(++id, "Orange", "Fruit", 0.80m, 20, 0.145m);
Product prod5 = new Product(++id, "Tomato", "Veg", 2.50m, 15, 0.110m);
Product prod6 = new Product(++id, "Onion", "Veg", 1.50m, 10, 0.105m);
Product prod7 = new Product(++id, "Lamb", "Meat", 4.50m, 10, 0.340m);
Product prod8 = new Product(++id, "Chicken", "Meat", 3.50m, 10, 0.907m);
```

Comment: I tried adding 'lstViewProducts.DataSource = products;' but it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you post the class you are writing currently and the product class too? This would help alot.
And just BTW: what kind of project arte you programming? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?